# How to change the URL when using NSURLSession downloadTaskWithResumeData:?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I use `NSURLSession downloadTaskWithURL`: to download a file, and use `NSURLSessionDownloadTask cancelByProducingResumeData:` to produce an `NSData` and save it to a local temp file.

Then I want to resume the download task by using `NSURLSession` `downloadTaskWithResumeData:`.

There's a problem, the URL I used to download the file is a temp url, I need to request a new URL to download the same file.
After using `downloadTaskWithResumeData:` , it helps me to create a `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` with the same URL as before.

How can I replace the URL with the new URL that I newly request?
Or how can I change the HTTP Request of this `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`?

How do you deal with the situation that resume a `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` with a different URL?

I'm thinking about to get the .tmp file that `NSURLSession` downloaded, and set the Range in HTTP Header, then write to this file with the new temp URL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that we can resume download if the path of the resource has been modified.

***According to Apple Developer Class Reference:***

> A download can be resumed only if the following conditions are met:
>
> - The resource has not changed since you first requested it
> - The task is an HTTP or HTTPS GET request
> - The server provides either the ETag or Last-Modified header (or both) in its response
> - The server supports byte-range requests
> - The temporary file hasn’t been deleted by the system in response to disk space pressure

Also as we see, there is no way we can modify URL programmatically while resuming a download. We just have an option to provided the partially downloaded data.